# Bibliography not changing from German to English while citing

Tags: bibliographies, languages

I am using a template from my university for my thesis. It was initially in German. I changed it completely to English. The Bibliography had the title set to 'Literaturverzeichnis', I changed the language settings in the Preamble, and it now says 'bibliography', but when I cite my references in the body of the document, it still uses German - like XYZ u.a instead of XYZ et al, or uses German labels - Bericht etc instead of report. I cannot find the setting. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. I have attached the code snippet and picture of output. As seen, it uses German 'und' instead of English 'and'. I have also included a code snippet from the Preamble which i think is relevant to the setting. I have tried permutations such as removing the German or changing the order, but to no avail.

```
\cite{energiewende2017} state that Germany must reduce its emissions by 95\% by the middle of this century. Gradual phaseout of almost all nuclear and coal fired power plants is also to take place in the next few years. Of the world's three biggest Carbon Dioxide emitters, China and India are fully committed to transitioning to low-emission sources of energy to tend to the energy needs of their billion-plus people.
```

[image]

```
\usepackage[german, USenglish]{babel} %Überschriften werden von LaTeX in der korrekten Sprache erzeugt  

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  %Ermöglicht Eingabe von Umlauten

\usepackage{babelbib}           % um Bibtex mit deutschen Styles zu verwenden
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In particular, please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: By the way, unless the editing software you employ is prehistoric, there should be no justification or reason for employing the input encoding `ansinew`. Assuming your editor is less than 5 years old, try `utf8` as the input encoding.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for your reply. I am a newbie to LaTex, that ansinew was in the Template, which I have minimally changed, and only so expressly where needed.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{dinatles}            Is this what you meant by bibliography style?

Comment: Thanks. Is the file `dinatles.bst` available online somewhere? It doesn't seem to be on the CTAN.

Comment: Thanks again, @Mico. I have the file bundled along with the template. I have created a temporary share location on the cloud, here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtrmR8H7W3RF_TIo-TdAlweD5yVB

Comment: @Anupam - Thanks for making the bst file available online. I've looked at it; sure enough, it's a style file designed to use "und" rather than "and", "u.a." rather than "et~al.", etc. I'll post an answer to show how to modify the language-related settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has stated in a comment that he/she uses a bibliography style called `dinatles` and has made the file `dinatles.bst` available online.

Assuming one needs to keep using this bibliographic style file and merely wishes change the language-specific settings from German to English, I suggest one proceed as follows:

- Make a copy of `dinatles.bst` and call the copy, say, `engdinatles.bst`. (You are obviously free to choose another name.)
- Open `engdinatles.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Go to line 109 of the file and change all German-language strings to equivalent English-language strings. E.g.,

  ```
  FUNCTION {push.bd}        { "vol." }
  FUNCTION {push.diplom}    { "Master's Thesis" }
  FUNCTION {push.disser}    { "Doctoral Thesis" }
  FUNCTION {push.forschung} { "Technical Report" }
  FUNCTION {push.hrsg}      { "Ed." }
  FUNCTION {push.in}        { "In:" }
  FUNCTION {push.isbn}      { "ISBN" }
  FUNCTION {push.issn}      { "ISSN" }
  FUNCTION {push.kap}       { "chap." }
  FUNCTION {push.nr}        { "nr." }
  FUNCTION {push.sn}        { "pages" }
  FUNCTION {push.s}         { "pp." }
  FUNCTION {push.siehe}     { "see" }
  FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "et~al." }
  FUNCTION {push.und}       { "and" }
  FUNCTION {push.url.name}  { "URL" }
  FUNCTION {push.veranst}   { "Event" }
  FUNCTION {push.von}       { "by" }
  FUNCTION {push.zugriff}   { "Accessed on" }
  ```

  Happily, the author of `dinatles.bst` showed sufficient foresight to centralize all language-specific settings!
- Save the file `engdinatles.bst` either in the directory where the main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If the latter option is chosen, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In the main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{dinatles}` to `\bibliographystyle{engdinatles}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully update all items.
- You should keep loading the `natbib` citation management package, but you probably no longer need load the `babelbib` package.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{aa,
  author = "Anne A. Author",
  title  = "Initial Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 3001,
  volume = 1,
  number = 2,
  pages  = "3-4",
}
@book{ab,
  author = "Anne A. Author and Brenda B. Buthor",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  address= "New York",
  publisher="Wiley",
  year   = 3002,
  pages  = "45",
}
@misc{abc,
  Author = "Anne A. Author and Brenda B. Buthor and Carla C. Cuthor",
  title  = "Final Thoughts",
  year   = 3003,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{engdinatles}

\begin{document}
\citet{aa}, \citet{ab}, \citet{abc}

\citep{aa}, \citep{ab}, \citep{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, @Mico. I had been trying to figure this out for the last 4 months. Finally, I decided to post this online. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Anupam - You're most welcome!